python flat. I constantly catch an exception when I close a tab or refresh a page
flet versins:
flet                  0.22.1
flet-core             0.22.1
flet-runtime          0.22.1

Here's the simplest code:
import flet as ft
from flet import Page, Text

def main(page: Page):
    page.title = "Hello, Flet!"
    page.add(Text("Hello, Flet!"))

ft.app(target=main)

I run the application as web: flet run .\minimal.py --web -p 4488
And as soon as I close the tab or refresh the page (F5), I immediately get an exception:
Exception in callback _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)
handle: <Handle _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 162, in _call_connection_lost
    self._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение

After that, everything works until I understand whether there is any harm. But it looks scary.
This is fine? Should I do something about this?


Exception in callback _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)


[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

(translated)
It's fine, don't worry about it. Your browser just closes the connection, and when Python tries to close the connection, Windows says that it's already been closed. It would be better if asyncio checked for the particular Windows error code 10054 and swallowed it, but for the time being, it doesn't.
